# ERR_ABORTED for Javascript message in the console

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

My Javascript code keeps showing this error in the console when I load my html page. I'm trying to import some Javascript code in VScode, through an app module so that I may reuse the code.

I'm running my code through localServer.

**Error**:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/js/js/slider net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

**app.js**:

```
import slider from './js/slider'

new slider();
```

Answer (score 2):

Where is your app.js located?
If it is located in "js" directory, replace the 1st line of your app.js into below.

```js
import slider from './slider';
```

404 response code means "requested file is not found".

Comment: Oh, i made a mistake. Where is your app.js located?
```
import slider from './slider';
```